# Want to output from 2 tables with same column name. Using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have 2 different tables with same columnname name tbl_specialty and tbl_student. I made a JOIN statement to join the 2 tables, now i want to output column name for table 1 and column name for table 2, how can i achieve this ? i am only getting a replication from one column.
Please help.

**My View**

```
 <?php
       foreach ($delegates->result() as $row )  
 {?>
       <tr>
          <td><a href=""> <?php echo $row->name; ?></a></td>
          <td class="center"><?php echo $row->job; ?></td>
          <td class="center"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
          <td class="center"><?php echo $row->workplace;?></td>
          <td class="center"><?php echo $row->country_name; ?></td>
      </tr>
```

**My model**

```
public function delegates_per_course()  {  
  $this>db>select('tbl_student.name,tbl_student.workplace,tbl_student.job,tbl_student.dob,tbl_student.email,tbl_student.mobile,tbl_country.country_name,tbl_specialty.name,tbl_country.country_id,tbl_country.country_name');
  $this->db->from('tbl_student');
  $this->db->join('tbl_country','tbl_student.country_id=tbl_country.country_id'); 
  $this->db->join('tbl_specialty','tbl_student.specialty_id=tbl_specialty.id'); 
  $this->db->order_by("tbl_country.country_name");
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('tbl_student.name as stud_name,tbl_student.workplace,tbl_student.job,tbl_student.dob,tbl_student.email,tbl_student.mobile,tbl_country.country_name,tbl_specialty.name as spec_name,tbl_country.country_id,tbl_country.country_name');
```

I have changed the query and create aliases for the same name columns like:

```
tbl_student.name as stud_name
tbl_specialty.name as spec_name
```

Now you can refer them properly by using there aliases. In absence of aliases **tbl_specialty.name** overrides values of **tbl_student.name**

Comment: Hey. thanks for the reply. How will i output it on my view. Instead of foreach ($delegates -> result () as $row ) what do i write ?

Comment: In the same way, just use $row->stud_name; and $row->spec_name; to refer these two columns

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

> Blockquote The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

In your case it will look like so:

```
SELECT columnname FROM tbl_specialty
UNION ALL
SELECT columnname FROM tbl_student;
```